# Create index of hyperlinks to visible sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have found and executed code successfully that creates a list of hyperlinks for each sheet in a workbook.  However, I have hidden sheets and do not want the hidden sheets to be included in the list of hyperlinks.  The code that works for all sheets is.

Is there a simple way to remove the hidden sheets from the resulting hyperlink list?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("P4").Select

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name Then
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
         "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("P4").Select

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name Then
            ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
             "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
Next sh
```